# Вывод на печать содержимого страницы

Tags: javascript, php

Существует несколько вопросов:

1. Как программно отключить верхние и нижние колонтитулы? (что бы на
   напечатанных листах не отображался адрес страницы, дата, номер и
   т.д)
2. Как программно разбить на страницы печатаемый текст? (в документ
   грузится несколько документов разной информации. Например, если
   первый документ занимает полторы страницы А4, то следующий за ним
   документ должен печататься с новой страницы).

Answer (score 1):

[Функции для работы с принтером.](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=printer)

Comment: прочитал я про эти функции php, но к сожалению не смог разобраться как подключить нужную dll и где ее взять, так как моя сборка денвера не хочет воспринимать их. Если не сложно подскажите.

Comment: боюсь что это функции работы с локальным принтером. При распечатке страници с сайта - пхп тут не причем, тут больше работа с JavaScript или css может помочь, если такое вообше возможно. В чем я сильно сомневаюсь. Идеальный вариант - отдавать PDF (будет отображатся сразу в окне броузера) распечатывает. Преобразовать html в pdf можно с помощью библиотеки mpdf или  аналогичных

Comment: Про php - допер, к тому же, они только работают до 2000 винды.
Благодарю, сейчас попробую.